# How to get UserId from localStorage

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, local-storage, next.js

I'm trying to build a blog, on a certain end point I want to list all the blogs created by specific user only, so i have stored the user info in Local Storage and I'm trying to get the username of the same, so that i can send the username to backend to get the blogs posted by that specific username.

set cookie

`import cookie from 'js-cookie';`

```
export const setCookie = (key, value) => {
    if (process.browser) {
        cookie.set(key, value, {
            expires: 1
        });
    }
};
```

get cookie

```
// get cookie
export const getCookie = key => {
    if (process.browser) {
        return cookie.get(key);
    }
};
```

set LocalStorage

```
export const setLocalStorage = (key, value) => {
    if (process.browser) {
        localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
};
```

isAuth action

```
export const isAuth = () => {
        if(process.browser ) {
            const cookieChecked = getCookie('token')
            if(cookieChecked){
                if(localStorage.getItem('user')){
                    return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'))
                }else{
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the Info that I have stored in the Local Storage

```
{_id: "5ece659149421c1f18c0c756", username: "2asjvwxkq", name: "test3", email: "test3@gmail.com", role: 0}
email: "test3@gmail.com"
name: "test3"
role: 0
username: "2asjvwxkq"
_id: "5ece659149421c1f18c0c756"
```

I tried doing `const username = isAuth() && isAuth().username`

But it is returning `undefined`

I want to send the `username` as a props to a component but the variable `username` is getting me undefined value.

**Update** : 
`JSON.stringify(username)` gives me the username but i am unable to send the same to backend

---

[image: Screenshot of LocalStorage key]

Comment: How do you set the items in the local storage? Maybe the key is wrong if you are getting undefined

Comment: @topched please see the updated question

Comment: That doesn't show which keys you pass in for the local storage. (Chrome)If you right click then select inspect, go to the application tab and select local storage on the left you will be able to see what the keys are

Comment: Then its failing above. Put a break point in that code and see whats going on

Comment: Are you running the code in the browser or in node?

Comment: Ah yes you dont have access to the windows local storage in node, this will not work

Comment: Update : tried opening it in browser too, not working

Comment: You are going to need to read the difference between server and client side. Reading through the next docs should clear up what is running where. Short answer is you cannot access the local storage in your node process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

**Suggestion 1** :

`const username = isAuth() ? isAuth().username : ''`
or use `useEffect()`  wherever necessary .

---

**Suggestion 2 :**

Instead of sending the props , directly call the function
`isAuth()`  inside the component you wanted to send in the first place ( if doing so won't affect anything ) and just to debug try doing `JSON.stringify(user)`

Answer (score 0):

Hı

I made simple for you. I think problem is `json.parse` method.
look my example

```
export const isAuth = () => {

    if (localStorage.getItem('user')) {
        return localStorage.getItem('user');
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

and in my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import {isAuth} from './isAuth'

function App() {
  localStorage.setItem('user', 'bahtiyar');
  const userName=isAuth();

  return (
    <div className="App">
     <div>{userName}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

look result:
[image]

Comment: Nope, it is not working, please see the updated question